# Doing a count() in an update in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, count

Is it possible to do a query like the following? I would like to do this in place of a stored procedure if possible.

for example, with two tables

```
UPDATE items
SET score='a', count=(SELECT COUNT(votes.id) AS C WHERE votes.uri = items.uri)
WHERE items.id = 'b'
```

Or something like that... Essentially doing a count on a table and using that value to update another table?

I don't even know if this question makes sense. Feel free to call me a moron if need be.

**Edit** sorry, this question might not make sense. I want to count table "B" and use that value to update table "A" in the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you've got the syntax basically right:

```
UPDATE items
SET score= 'a', count = (SELECT COUNT(votes.id)
    FROM votes WHERE votes.uri = items.uri)
WHERE items.id = 'b'
```

This is called a correlated subquery. It's correlated because you refer to the table in the outer query in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What you're looking for is [mysql_affected_rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-affected-rows.html), you can call it immediately after the query to see how many records were updated.</strike>

You are actually very close! How about this:

```
UPDATE items SET score='a', count = (SELECT COUNT(votes.id) FROM votes WHERE votes.uri = items.uri) WHERE items.id = 'b'
```

edit: Rafe posted his solution first.

Comment: not quite... I want to count a table and use that value to update another table in the same query.

Comment: Ohh yeah I totally misunderstood your question. So you're saying you want to use the result of a query... in another query! Can you just do two queries and store the result of the first?